# When is cache_menu flushed?

Tags: 7, caching, navigation

I was caching some goodies related to the menu, and putting it in the 'cache_menu' bin, assuming they would get cleared whenever someones edits the menu.

```
cache_set($cachekey, $mymenu, 'cache_menu', CACHE_TEMPORARY);
```

When I edit the menu, it isn't cleared. When is it cleared, then?

In what sense is it different from the *cache* bin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [`menu_link_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7.x), you will see that it calls `menu_cache_clear()` to clear only the cache of the menu the menu item belongs to. Other entries in the menu cache are not cleared.

The entire menu cache is only cleared when [`menu_cache_clear_all()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_cache_clear_all/7.x) is called directly (eg. by `menu_enable()`, which runs whenever a module is enabled) or indirectly (often through `menu_rebuild()` or `drupal_flush_all_caches()`).

If I were you, I would store my own data in the default 'cache' bin. I consider the menu cache to be private to the menu system; I don't want to touch it and accidentally mess something up. To clear my cache data at the right moment, I would implement [`hook_meu_link_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_insert/7.x) and/or [`hook_meu_link_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_update/7.x) and clear/rebuild my cache data from there.

Comment: did that, works (hook must be in a module, not in a theme). used `cache_clear_all($cachekeystart, 'cache', true); drupal_set_message('Custom Menu cache cleared'); ` on insert, update and delete

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That sounds right, if I'm not mistaken, only alter hooks (eg. hook_form_alter) can live in both themes and modules.

Comment: Alters, preprocess, and process hooks can be called from both.